# Dragging an element inside an anchor in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I'm having issues with some HTML5 Drag-and-drop code on Firefox, when the draggable element is inside an anchor tag.

Boiled down to the minimum reproducible code, here's what I have currently:

```
<a href="#">
  <div id="dragger" draggable="true"></div>
</a>
```

And the following Javascript:

```
var d = document.getElementById('dragger');

d.ondragstart = (e) => {
  console.log('dragstart');
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text', '');
  d.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
};

d.ondragend = (e) => {
  console.log('dragend');
  d.style.backgroundColor = '';
};
```

*Also here in a [JSBin](http://output.jsbin.com/fuwuyucuxi).*

In Chrome, everything works as expected (the handlers are executed), but in Firefox, neither of the handlers run. Instead, I get the default browser behaviour of dragging the `<a>` tag.

*Side note: In some places in my application, I've been able to get around this by making the link the draggable element and everything works fine there, but this isn't possible everywhere unfortunately.*

Answer (score 2):

Heh, I've worked on exactly the same problem this morning :)
Looks like a bug in Mozilla as it assigns a value to dataTransfer that has never been deliberately assigned in javascript.

The following I find a workaround:

```
    <a draggable="false" ondragstart="event.dataTransfer.setData('text', 'YourDataHere');" ondragover="event.preventDefault()">
        <div draggable="true" ondragstart="event.dataTransfer.setData('text', 'YourDataHere');" ondragover="event.preventDefault()">
      ...
        </div>
    </a>
```

So setting dataTransfer in anchor provides your expected behavior in Mozilla. Setting draggable="false" for the same node prevents other browsers from dragging the anchor. Making inner  draggable and setting dataTransfer there gives that it works normally in all browsers I tested (IE11, Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

Removing href-attribute entirely from a-tag helped in my case in favor of onclick-Attribute. You may fix missing mouse pointer due to missing href with CSS "cursor: pointer;".

And calling event.preventDefault() in event handler was necessary to avoid default behavior.